# Do touch events not work with text-input elements in iPad Safari?

Tags: ipad, element, touch, textinput

In iPad Safari, I have programmed a DIV's touch-events so that when you touch inside the DIV and hold your finger there for 500 ms, the DIV's background color changes.

When I try to move the code over to a text-input element (inside a fieldset), making it the touch-target instead of the DIV, the code doesn't work. The text-input becomes selected in spite of this CSS:

```
    input[type=text] {-webkit-touch-callout:none; -webkit-user-select:none }
```

Is there no way to intercept the touch events of a text-input element in iPad Safari and handle them in a custom manner, preventing default behavior? Or is there something additional that I must do to get the input to support this? I've tried with and without a dummy click handler:  onclick="void(0)".

This is the doc I'm following the documentation *[Handling Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7)*.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you posted your code, but I'm thinking you probably just need to prevent the default behavior on touch events. This looks something like this if using jQuery:

```
$("#ID")
        .bind("touchstart",
            function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //do something
            })
        .bind("touchmove",
            function (e) {
                if (e.preventDefault) { 
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
                //do something
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable and make your input readonly:

```
<input type="text" readonly />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't call `preventDefault()` in your handler code, the browser will automatically pass the touch event through to the default implementation (after you think you've handled it).  The default implementation is to select the field.

So, in your case, call `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` in your handler, and return false.  This prevents the event from bubbling further.  Then you can totally control your input element.

Caveat: You'll then also lose the default behavior of the input field!  In other words, you'll not be able to input text into the field!  Or if the input field is a `<select>`, you won't be able to pull up the list etc.

I suppose what you really want is: 1) If user presses and hold for 500ms, then turn yellow, 2) and/or on release activate the input field.  In that case, you'll have to manually refire the event upwards when you really want to use the input field.

This kind of situation is very common when programming the iPad.  For example, in many cases you'd want to detect a touch-drag motion (even on an input field) and interpret it as a move, but interpret a touch-release motion (without moving) as a click to activate the input field.  You have to do what I suggest above: `preventDefault()` and refire event when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I need the input to accept input like a normal text input. I want to create a context-menu on the inputs to display characters not found on the virtual keyboard's own built-in context-menus, i.e. when you hold your finger down for a while on, e.g., [a] you will get a popup showing variant forms of the letter [a] -- accented a, umlauted-a, etc.  I need to give the user a way to enter variants forms of the letters [d] and [t] which Apple did not include on its virtual keyboard. But the user won't always need to do this--only when applicable.

Comment: @Tim, in that case, you'll need to trap (i.e. do preventDefault and stopPropagation) on touchstart, touchmove and touchend.  Then you decide whether it is a click (i.e. origin on touchstart is close to touchend).  If it is a click, you time it (i.e. time at touchend - touchstart).  If time is short, refire the event as a normal onclick upwards to the DOM.  If time is long, do your special thing.

Comment: thanks once again. I need to preserve the selection info (i.e selectionStart and selectionEnd) so the character chosen from the context menu attached to the textinput can be inserted at the correct location.  The user is typing a word that needs the special character not found on the virtual keyboard, and may be trying to insert the character rather than append it, or replace selected text with the character.